# PowerBi using wrong kerberos credentials

Tags: odbc, powerbi-desktop, kerberos, impala

i'm having an issue using power bi to connect to impala database throught ODBC with kerberos auth.

When I test the connection everything works fine. If I try to import the data on exel everything works.

when I try on power bi to import data results in this error

> ODBC: ERROR [HY000] [Cloudera][DriverSupport] (1170) Unexpected response received from server. Please ensure the server host and port specified for the connection are correct.

I verified the odbclog and it's using a wrong username instead of the kerberos one I configured:

> Oct 06 11:11:45.609 ERROR 3176 Simba::ThriftExtension::TETSaslClientTransport::SaslLoggingCallback: ::LogUsername: User name returned by GetUsernameEx(NameUserPrincipal): <WRONG_USER>
> Oct 06 11:11:46.241 INFO  3176 Simba::ThriftExtension::TETSaslClientTransport::SaslLoggingCallback: AutoOutputSecBufferDesc::~AutoOutputSecBufferDesc: +++++ enter +++++
> Oct 06 11:11:46.242 ERROR 3176 Simba::ODBC::Connection::SQLDriverConnectW: [Cloudera][DriverSupport] (1170) Unexpected response received from server. Please ensure the server host and port specified for the connection are correct.

can anyone help?

Thank a lot in advance

Comment: are the username, password defined in ODBC properly?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: In ODBC everything works. Tried to test connection and it works and tried to import from excel and it works. Only Powerbi is giving problems with  the connection